# Change style when dragging mouse over appended div

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I'm trying to create a "grid" consisted of divs created and appended with JS on which, when i'm dragging my mouse over each div, i want it's style to change. Something similar to drawing with plain divs, without the use of canvas. 
Is this possible?

I wrote the following code to append 50 elements, and used mouseUp() and mouseDown() event listeners.
When i have my mouse pressed over any element, the changes apply only on the first one.

```js
var c = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      var e = document.createElement("div");
        e.id = "box";
        e.className = "box";
        e.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);
        e.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp);
        c.appendChild(e);
        }
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(c);
    
 function mouseDown() {
   document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "DOWN";
   document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "red";
   }
 function mouseUp() {
   document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "UP";
   document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "black";
   }
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #000;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.box:hover {
  background: blue !important;

}

.bg-blue {
  background: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Setting an `id` should be single instance unique. Currently you're setting all generated divs to be the same `id="box"` so when it goes to use `getElementById` it's doing what it's supposed to do by spec and grabbing the first (and considered only valid instance) of `id="box"` Either give each a unique ref or pass `this` as the arg so each element is treated as its own instance. PS tip; for the sake of readibility, indents and proper code structure would make whoever has to maintain your stuff in the future not hate ya :D

Comment: @ChrisW. Thank you for your answer and suggestion, you are totally right! I messed up my indentation trying to paste the code using Ctrl+K, then i found Ctrl+M as a better option, but i forgot to make it more readable before posting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an argument to an event listener as a event and use it's target to apply your desired changes. Just like below:

```js
    var c = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    var e = document.createElement("div");
    e.className = "box";
    e.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);
    e.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp);
    c.appendChild(e);}
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(c);
    function mouseDown(event) {
    event.target.innerHTML = "DOWN";
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";}
    function mouseUp(event) {
    event.target.innerHTML = "UP";
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = "black";}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #000;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.box:hover {
  background: blue !important;

}

.bg-blue {
  background: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Right now, if i click on a div and release my mouse on another div, the changes apply only on the div i first clicked, and the last div my cursor is over when i release the mouse. Is it possible to change the state of the divs in between while i'm dragging my mouse over them from div A (mousedown) to div B (mouseup)?

Comment: @Mike_R If it solved your question's issue then accept it as an answer ;D. Now about your new issue, it seems doable, a simple approach is to basically keep the mouse-down event target stored somewhere and reuse it on mouse-up. I'll leave it to you as an exercise. If it keeps you from proceeding, please do come back!

Comment: Answer accepted!  I've been trying to achieve it by using a while loop without success, i'll try to do it the way you suggested! Thank you very much :D